# Loop through points with a step size, inclusive of end point

Tags: java

I have a start and end point, I'd like to loop through them using a specific step size, but I need to ensure that the end point is included. Is the following the best way to accomplish this, or is there a better way?

```
Double start = 2.1;
Double end = 5.3;
Double step = 0.6;
for(Double i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
    // do stuff

    if(i != end && (i + step) > end) {
        i = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would multiply by 10 and use int here, you could end up with some rounding issues with doubles

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question, OP does the same thing, but he wants a different result.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I disagree with you, the fact that the OP wants a loop with end included doesn't really matter in here it's `<` vs `<=`

Comment: @RC. OP has an equality check on double values, a big no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should prefer integers for your loop variables, especially when the interval divides in the whole number of steps. In case this is not possible you could use double values, but you need to be careful to avoid precision pitfalls of double computations.

Comparing doubles for equality is not a good idea. A better approach is to use Math.min to cap i at the value of end:

```
for(double i = start; i < end+step; i += step) {
    double pt = Math.min(end, i);
    ... // use pt here
}
```

Comment: in your solution, i is always less then end.

Comment: @KristjanKica not really, see the stopping condition.

Comment: You need to do it like this;
`for(double i = start; i < =end+step; i += step) {
    double pt = Math.min(end, i);
    ... // use pt here
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use an instruction outside the loop , to do the `end` part.
Don't use `double` in iterations. Because of the way floating point numbers are stored, you may `2.1 +0.6` as `2.7` but `as 2.69999999999999999999` for example. In this case, multiply by 10 to achieve what you want.

Your solution is wrong. You make i=end, but it is then added by step, so you dont iterate. You could use:

```
 if(i != end && (i + step) > end) {
        i = end-step;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of integer steps required and use these to control the loop. When you reach the final step you use the `end` value.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Double start = 2.1;
    Double end = 5.3;
    Double step = 0.6;

    int steps = (int)Math.round((end-start)/step);      
    if(start + steps*step < end) steps++;

    double pos = start;
    for(int s=0; s<=steps; )
    {
        System.out.println(pos);            
        s += 1;
        pos = (s==steps) ? end : start + step*s;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2.1
2.7
3.3
3.9
4.5
5.1
5.3
```

Note that for the intermediate steps we calculate the position using a multiplication rather than repeated addition. I can't find a reference at the moment but my understanding is that this incurs less floating point "drift". This seems to be borne out. If we use:

```
pos = (s==steps) ? end : pos+step;
```

to calculate the next `pos` then we get as output:

```
2.1
2.7
3.3000000000000003
3.9000000000000004
4.5
5.1
5.3
```